# vuetify sub menu in sidebar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to add a submenu to a title in the vuetify sidebar menu I designed. I edited the code and data as below, but I can't make any changes.

this is my code

```
      <v-list flat class="mt-50">
    <v-list-item-group v-model="selectedItem" color="black">
      <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" active-class="border" class="mr-3" :ripple="false" :to="item.link" link>
        <v-list-item-icon>
          <v-icon v-text="item.icon"></v-icon>
        </v-list-item-icon>

        <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item>
      <v-list-item v-for="child in items.child" :key="child.title">
        <v-list-item-title :to="child.route">{{ child.title }}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list-item-group>
  </v-list>
```

the data which is my use

```
 selectedItem: 0,
 items: [
      { icon: 'mdi-account-key', title: 'Users', link: '/dashboard/test' },
      { icon: 'mdi-shopping', title: 'tests', link: '/dashboard/test2' },
      { icon: 'mdi-marker', title: 'tests2', link: '/dashboard/test3' },
          childs: [
            { title: 'basic', link: '/dashboard/table/basic' },
            { title: 'data', link: '/dashboard/table/data' },
            { title: 'responsive', link: '/dashboard/table/responsive' },
            { title: 'editable', link: '/dashboard/table/editable' },
            { title: 'filter', link: '/dashboard/table/filter' },
            { title: 'pagination', link: '/dashboard/table/pagination' },
            { title: 'search', link: '/dashboard/table/search' },
            { title: 'sort', link: '/dashboard/table/sort' },
            { title: 'selection', link: '/dashboard/table/selection' },
            { title: 'tree', link: '/dashboard/table/tree' },
            { title: 'custom', link: '/dashboard/table/custom' },
          ],
```

Comment: What's the question? What do you mean you can't make any changes?

Answer (score 0):

Try like following snippet (add `v-list-group` to toggle submenu, also `items.child` doesn't exist in your data, only `childs`):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      selectedItem: 0,
      items: [{icon: 'mdi-account-key', title: 'Users', link: '/dashboard/test'}, {icon: 'mdi-shopping', title: 'tests', link: '/dashboard/test2'}, {icon: 'mdi-marker', title: 'tests2', link: '/dashboard/test3'},],
      childs: [{title: 'basic', link: '/dashboard/table/basic'}, {title: 'data', link: '/dashboard/table/data'}, {title: 'responsive', link: '/dashboard/table/responsive'}, {title: 'editable', link: '/dashboard/table/editable'}, {title: 'filter', link: '/dashboard/table/filter'}, {title: 'pagination', link: '/dashboard/table/pagination'}, { title: 'search', link: '/dashboard/table/search'}, {title: 'sort', link: '/dashboard/table/sort'}, {title: 'selection', link: '/dashboard/table/selection'}, {title: 'tree', link: '/dashboard/table/tree'}, {title: 'custom', link: '/dashboard/table/custom'},],
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
          <v-list flat class="mt-50">
            <v-list-item-group v-model="selectedItem" color="black">
              <!--<v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" active-class="border" class="mr-3" :ripple="false" :to="item.link" link>-->
              <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" active-class="border" class="mr-3" :ripple="false" link>
                <v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-icon v-text="item.icon"></v-icon>
                </v-list-item-icon>
                <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
              
              <v-list-group no-action sub-group>
                <template v-slot:activator>
                  <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>Submenu</v-list-item-title>
                  </v-list-item-content>
                </template>
                <v-list-item v-for="child in childs" :key="child.title">
                  <v-list-item-title>{{ child.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                  <!--<v-list-item-title :to="child.route">{{ child.title }}</v-list-item-title>-->
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list-group>
              
            </v-list-item-group>
          </v-list>
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    
  </script>
</body>
```